# How to execute ONE simulator for getting results

Tags: one-simulator

I executed Config file in ONE simulator then i got the GUI with nodes moment but i don't know how to execute and how to get the results in ONE simulator.
i want to know what is the command for getting the results in ONE simulator.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You see the results of the configured simulation in real-time in the GUI. However, you probably want to enable some [reports](https://github.com/akeranen/the-one/wiki/README#reports) for post-processing.